# Is it possible to access the updated value right after the set function without waiting to second re-rendering finished?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that would trigger a set function and is expected to make use of the updated value to do sth else

Here is an example

```
export default function App() {

const [value,setValue] = useState(0)
  const increaseValueaAndAlertUpdatedValue = () => {
    setValue((prev)=>{return prev + 1})
    alert(`updated value: ${value}`) //expect the first click is to show the updated value, but not current value. It is not necessary to be plus, but I want the call back function here is to show the updated value after setValue when clicking it. 
  }
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React TypeScript.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={increaseValueaAndAlertUpdatedValue}>increaseValueaAndAlertUpdatedValue</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I really need to make use of the updated value instead of the current value there. But now it seems the updated value could only be access after a re-rendering.

In my case, value is not a simple number value, it is a giant object.

Way I also tried: (wrapped it with a setTimeout) But, obviously, it doesnt work. I guess it is a problem of closure

```
setTimeout(()=>{ alert(`updated value: ${value}`)},1000)
```

useEffect and useLayoutEffect are not solution to my situation becuase I need the value after that the set function fired and use the updated value in my "alert function" ; not in other useEffect or layoutEffect.

Comment: maybe you can try `useLayoutEffect` it fires before re-render (before showing changes to the user), allowing you to "correct" your object https://react.dev/reference/react/useLayoutEffect

Comment: Could you provide an example of doing it for this case? It doesnt seems obvouis to me. useLayout seems to suit for layout caluculation more.

Comment: Updated in my post. Dont think useLayout works

Answer (score 0):

Can't you perform the action in callback method passed in setValue.

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function handleClick() {
    setCount((prevCount) => {
      const newCount = prevCount + 1;
      runAlert(newCount); // ---> runAlert will show the alert
      return newCount;
    });
  }

  const runAlert = (state) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert(state);
    }, 0); // --> required so it won't get executed as soon as alert is seen
  };

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>{count} Increase counter</button>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to do something like this? You already know the new value inside your state update and alert function so you can call alert like this:

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [value,setValue] = useState(0)

  const increaseValueaAndAlertUpdatedValue = () => {
    const oldValue = value // Save old value before setValue() -- IMPORTANT!
    setValue((prev)=>{return prev + 1})
    alert(`updated value: ${oldValue + 1}`) // Use oldValue + 1 here
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React TypeScript.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={increaseValueaAndAlertUpdatedValue}>increaseValueaAndAlertUpdatedValue</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**BUT!!!** Since you don't use your value for rendering then much better solution in this case is to use useRef hook:

```
import {useRef} from 'react';
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const value = useRef(0)
  const increaseValueaAndAlertUpdatedValue = () => {
    value.current++
    alert(`updated value: ${value.current}`)
  }
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React TypeScript.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={increaseValueaAndAlertUpdatedValue}>increaseValueaAndAlertUpdatedValue</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And yeah! You get stateless component, so no unnecessary rerenders when the counter is increased.

You can read [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef) about useRef().

Answer (score 0):

move the alert function outside of the component and pass in the updated value as a parameter to the function. This way, the value will be updated in the function and you can use it without waiting for the re-rendering to finish.

```
const alertUpdatedValue = (value) => {
  alert(`updated value: ${value}`)
}

const increaseValueaAndAlertUpdatedValue = () => {
  setValue((prev)=>{return prev + 1})
  alertUpdatedValue(value)
}
```